# I have got something wrong in my algorithm

Tags: java

I want to wrote the algorithm of exercise from Project Euler #2. Here is the exercise:

> "Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms."

And here is my algorithm:

```
public class FibonacciSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 2;
        int sum = a + b;
        while (a < 4000000 && b < 4000000){
            a += b;
            if (a < 4000000){
                sum = a + sum;
                b += a;
                if (b < 4000000){
                    sum = b + sum;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }  
}
```

Program calculated answer: `7049154`
But Euler says that it is wrong answer. I tried several ways of it but was unsuccessful. 
Tell me please where did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks suspiciously like you're starting with 0 and 2 instead of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

1) At first, you chose incorrect start values. You end up with the following sequence 0, 2, 4, 6, 10... 
2) You need to sum up only even numbers.
3) Your code is overcomplicated. Try to just find a fibonacci number which is less than four million. And then just add the summation

Answer (score -3):

Here you go ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int g=0,h=0,v=1,i=1;
    while (i<4000000) {
        if ((~i & 1)) h+=i;
        g = v;
        v = i;
        i = g + v;
    }
    printf("> %d \n",h);
    return 0;
};
```